# Посоветуйте язык программирования для Windows

Tags: windows, design

Хорошо стою на PHP, JS.
Нужен не консольный, а десктопный язык, с ООП.
Сейчас нужно написать программку для работы с БД (MySQL) на сервере. Несложную, но с графическим интерфейсом.
В планах написать чтото похожее и для Android.

Нужен совет и рекомендации знающих!

В этом вопросе я нуб. Просто давно изучал Паскаль, и там был страшный черный экран ожидавший ввода. А от языка программирования требуется: ООП, Легкость изучения, Возможность работать с серверной БД.

А так в языках программирования я уже потерялся ... В интернете нашел такие понятия как: С++, С#, Delphi, Python, Java. А какая разница между ними - понятия не имею. И, тем более, что мне подходит...

Comment: пардон, а что такое "консольный язык программирования"?

Comment: ну это я от тупости написал)... мне нужна программа с графическим интерфейсом, а не та которая запустится через консоль. (*.сmd)

Comment: что-то не припоминаю ни одного серьезного (честно говоря, и несерьезного тоже) языка, который бы позволял создавать консольные приложения, но не позволял оконные. А по сабжу - вам стоит уточнить, какие критерии языка важны. В противном случае ответом на ваш вопрос будет практически любой язык от Java до C++

Comment: @DreamChild: Ну, C++ в рамках стандарта даже приличной консоли не имеет, только вывод в режиме tty :-) Вся графика — системно-зависимые библиотеки.

Но вообще-то вы правы, на почти современных языках есть графические привязки. (Кроме может быть функциональных типа Haskell/OCaml.)

Comment: В этом вопросе я нуб. Просто давно изучал Паскаль, и там был страшный черный экран ожидавший ввода. 
А от языка программирования требуется: 
ООП, Легкость изучения, Возможность работать с серверной БД. 

А так в языках программирования я уже потерялся ... 
В интернете нашел такие понятия как: С++, С#, Delphi, Python, Java 
А какая разница между ними понятия не имею. и тем более что мне подходит...

Comment: если говорить о простоте изучения, то явные трудности после php могут возникнуть со строго типизированными языками. А если в языке еще и сборки мусора нет, то поначалу вы его вообще можете возненавидеть. Присоединюсь к вышеотписавшимся - смотрите в сторону C#. Он довольно прост, удобен, в его концепцию хорошо вписаны ORM и вообще он мимими

Comment: @DreamChild Странно читать Ваши комментарии. Неужели в XXI веке можно не знать, что лучший язык для программирования под Windows -- Visual Basic? (Ежели склероз не изменяет, то на нём даже Raional Rose написана -- куда уж ООПней)

Comment: @alexlz я, наверное, по утрам плохо отличаю сарказм. Это вы ведь шутите, надеюсь?

Comment: @DreamChild ну где-то так. Хотя фраза "Чайник с VB не так опасен, как чайник с C++" ((с) кажется А.Москаль) мне кажется правильной. А к тому же VB.NET вполне имеет место быть

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Фирма Microsoft (которая как бы законодатель моды на Windows) продвигает связку C#/WPF для десктопных приложений. Под неё существуют [многочисленные ORM-фреймворки](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_object-relational_mapping_software#.NET), например, [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee712907) и [NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/wikis/howtonh/your-first-nhibernate-based-application.aspx).

Если вам нужно серверное приложение, а не десктопное, я бы порекомендовал связку [ASP.NET MVC/Entity Framework](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc) под C#.

Comment: Нужно десктопное. Ну база данных должна быть на сервере. Так как от нее работают пару сайтов. думаю буду пробывать то что Вы советуете! (C#/WPF)

Comment: @myvzar: удачи!

Answer (score 7):

Посмотрите в сторону .NET Framework(С#, etc...), или Qt(С++, etc...)
Есть проекты вроде PHP-Qt, но использовать их я бы не советовал.

**UPD**. Qt является кроссплатформенным, поэтому портировать на адроид будет много проще.

Answer (score 4):

[@myvzar](/users/7058/myvzar), Вы пишете

```
и там был страшный черный экран ожидавший ввода.
```

А это тот начальный этап, который Вам обязательно предстоит пройти на любом языке, перед тем, как начать работать с GUI.

Для M$ же, видимо, лучшим выбором будет C#, но если Вы не хотите навсегда зависнуть в форточках, то попробуйте освоить Python.

Answer (score 4):

Java. Быстро на ней пишется, быстро изучается. Горы документации на русском языке. Да и под андроид потом писать пригодится. Там ведь тоже java.

Answer (score 3):

> > В планах написать чтото похожее и для Android.

Java + swt

Answer (score 3):

Если вы планируете потом портировать программу на Android, то, как сказали ранее, вам поможет Java.
Но Android также поддерживает язык C++ (JNI/JNA). Моё мнение таково: на Java легко писать, но программы выполняются относительно медленно. На С++ писать сложнее, но код выполняется намного быстрее.
Я никому не навязываю своё мнение, так что решать вам)

Comment: Python для Android тоже есть.

Answer (score 1):

Есть очень хороший функциональный язык [autoIT](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/). Для маленьких десктопных приложений очень даже ничего.

Answer (score -1):

Учили паскаль, хотите кодить для винды, тогда вам прямая дорога к embarcadero, 5 кликов мышью и полноценная программа для работы с БД готова.

П.С. что что а быстрее чем в  ней сделать программу не реально ни на одном другом языке, что бы там не говорили... (хотя бы потому что очень много компонентов, сводят вашу работу к простому перетаскиванию мыши нужного вам на форму.)

Comment: Блин, а мужики-то и не знали. Большой толпой писали систему билинга телефонных разговоров (правда это было 10 лет назад и ранее). А тут пять кликов -- и всё готово. Одно их оправдывает, вероятно embarcadero тогда ещё не было...

Comment: Как ни странно, но это ответ. )